# Messaging queue application

Tags: java, msmq, openmq

I´m told to develop a message queue like MSMQ for some apps, but it has to be written in Java so it's able to work on a Linux server. A co-worker tested openmq via glassfish but it's very slow, even having both apps on the same computer. It would delay each message for 1 second on a slow computer and .8 on a fast one, ive read his code and everything seems fine, delays seem to be caused by openmq glassfish functions(not his code).

Ive read a bunch of things that are related to the subject but i can´t find a library or something(ive seen zeromq,openmq and i dont know if they would suit because they seem to be oriented for managing and not providing the service). The only one i think suits my needs is MSMQ and i am not able to use it for the reasons i gave before.

In a couple of months it would be used to communicate at least 200 live applications

The main reason of this question is to try get a suggestion of what should i use or if someone had used openmq with glassfish and works cool and i should re ckeck that code to look for issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ActiveMQ? Easy to set up and use and can handle a hell of lot of messages. We always use it with Spring's JMS templates for pain free messaging.

http://activemq.apache.org/

Comment: ive tried, but i have not seen examples or tutorials on how to use it,  ill give it a shot, if you know how can i educate myself about it i would be very grateful

Comment: I would first look at the wikipedia entry on JMS (of which activeMQ is an implementation of) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service Then get ActiveMQ up and running on your host http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html Once it is running you don't need to then mess around with it, as all the interaction is taken care of by the clients you implement. I would then definitely recommend using spring http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-jms.html